stream-chat: Nothing appears on small screens
here's the relevant code of chat-stream in my NextJs app:

Chat.tsx

<div className="flex h-full w-full">
  <StreamChat
    client={chatClient}
    theme={
      resolvedTheme === "dark"
        ? "str-chat__theme-dark"
        : "str-chat__theme-light"
    }
  >
    <ChatSidebar open={sidebarOpen} onClose={() => setSidebarOpen(false)} />
    <ChatChannel
      open={!sidebarOpen}
      openSidebar={() => setSidebarOpen(true)}
    />
  </StreamChat>
</div>


ChatSideBar.tsx

<div
  className={cn(
    "size-full flex-col border-e md:flex md:w-72",
    open ? "flex" : "hidden",
  )}
>
  <MenuHeader onClose={onClose} />
  <ChannelList
    filters={{
      type: "messaging",
      members: { $in: [user.id] },
    }}
    showChannelSearch
    options={{ state: true, presence: true, limit: 8 }}
    sort={{ last_message_at: -1 }}
    additionalChannelSearchProps={{
      searchForChannels: true,
      searchQueryParams: {
        channelFilters: {
          filters: { members: { $in: [user.id] } },
        },
      },
    }}
    Preview={ChannelPreviewCustom}
  />
</div>


ChatChannel.tsx

<div className={cn("w-full md:block", !open && "hidden")}>
  <Channel>
    <Window>
      <CustomChannelHeader openSidebar={openSidebar} />
      <MessageList />
      <MessageInput />
    </Window>
  </Channel>
</div>

My problem is that if the screen is small, ChatSideBar will disappear because of this:
  <div
      className={cn(
        "size-full flex-col border-e md:flex md:w-72",
        open ? "flex" : "hidden",
      )}
    >

That's okay when ChatChannel is there and there is a conversation displayed.
But, when the user initially creates an account, he has no conversation, so ChatChannel renders nothing.
And so if the screen small neither ChatChannel will appear nor the ChatSideBar and the user will see nothing.
Ideally, ChatChannel should always render something. But, I couldn't find how to get it to do that.
Anyone has any idea how to solve this?
